# How to find the parametric equations for: $zx + zy - xy = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

I'm trying to find the parametric equation for $zx + zy - xy = 0$ or equivalent $z = \frac{xy}{x+y}$ but couldn't find any hint in the web neither in a couple of calculus books for this particular equation.

I have no clue about how to proceed :(

Answer (score 2):

Big hint:  When $xyz\neq 0$,  $$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x}$$